# im trying to host my flask api on heroku, but when passing the path to my app, i get an import error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-restful

the error im getting: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

My folder structure:

-Backend

> 

- `__init__`.py
- run.py
- procfile

__init.py:

```
has the create app method
```

run.py:

```
from . import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = create_app("config")
   app.run(debug=True)
```

procfile:

web: gunicorn run:app

EDIT:

I rearranged the app structure by which:

- Backend

> - **init**.py
> - procifle
> - extensions.py
> - src
>
> > - init.py
> > - run.py

init.py:

```
empty
```

src/init.py:

```
from ..extensions import db,migrate
has the create app method
```

src/run.py:

```
from src import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = create_app("config")
  app.run(debug=True)
```

so now the new error is:

- from ..extensions import db
- ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Edit #2:
another thing to point out is, that suppose in the run.py i do the following:
from Backend import create_app()

> I get the following error: no module named "Backend" why could that be?

Has anyone faced a similar issue and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on new information I think we can get you home.

1.) Move `run.py` next to the procfile (same dir). That "run file" should be in that top level dit at `/app/run.py` in Heroku.

A good basic pattern for file organization is to "module" everything (a dir with a `__init__.py` file). Then all imports are from the top level `run.py` [where the process is running from] walking subfolders. As long as you traverse down into imports things stay pretty stable.  If you are trying to navigate up dirs it becomes problematic.

Resolve any imports, it can be tricky at first but soon becomes a way of thinking.

2.) Move `extensions.py` into `src` (for now) and import `from src import foo`

The following is the pattern in all my active Django and similar apps running in Heroku. Same layout I have been using for many years. In the following screenshot `manage.py` is the Django equivalent of  your `run.py`. I am not using the docker image on this app, so that is not in the equation, just code and dependencies.

[image: Screen grab of my Django dir sent to Heroku]

Your problems are totally understandable, it's easy to take for granted all the times other Python devs do this.

Comment: i tried rearranging the folder structure but to no avail, the error is now in the __init__ which has relative imports,  so its like digging deeper in a rabbit hole. and yes, i definitely use explicit imports, hence i don't know where the issue is

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package, that's the new error I got btw, i will add it to the question to provide further insight perhaps it helps. @Marc

Comment: Looks like you are fixed. Sorry I am not on-line every day (well, I don't hit SO everyday).  As you build the app, continue to use modules and always import from the run.py directory - "top down"